# How to temporarily store user attribute after login in ASP.NET MVC 5 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I’ve managed the login process using Identity. However, I also want to temporarily store the user coupon code till his session expires. I’ve searched in numerous forums, only to find solutions based on Claims. When I implemented Claims, I realised that it creates persistent entries in Database. I only want to temporarily save the coupon. Does Identity manages some session of its own so that I can extend it to save my data ? If not then , is creating a separate session variable the only solution?

Comment: Both solutions sound very strange because as long as the user keeps activity in the browser the coupon would be available for another X minutes after the last request. It seems like keeping a persistent record with an expiration date/time would make more sense from a marketing perspective, otherwise the user could theoretically setup a script to keep the coupon valid forever. Or worse, the coupon could expire due to inactivity (or an app pool restart) before the user has a chance to use it.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is you will have to use a session or/and Cookies.

[HttpContext.Session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session(v=vs.110).aspx) Property:

```
Session[UserId] = "CouponCode";
```

Session is used to store per-user information for the current Web session on the server. It supports using a database server as the back-end store.